# Pictures (Assets) not showing (error 404)

Tags: assets

My pictures were not showing - even if everything looked great (files were available at the right place, template code was correct, ...). My first reaction was to check the htaccess file, but (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

I called my directory "icons" (www.example.com/icons/) which was obviously not a good idea. After renaming the directory to "img/icons" it works perfect!

Comment: FWIW, `icons` isn't reserved by Craft, but a lot of Apache configurations have something like this set in their default `httpd.conf` file, which is probably what you were running into: `Alias /icons/ /usr/local/apache/icons/` See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433631/apache-how-to-override-index-of-icons